# Are variables consuming different memory blocks in servers for each user?

Tags: php, memory, server, allocation

Let us suppose there is a php script in our server and we have something like

```
<?php
class Car{
   private $door = "door";
   private $wheel = "wheel";
}

$car = new Car();
?>
```

written. When I open the php page, it should create an instance then allocate a memory for variables. How does it treat when multiple users are online at this page? Does it allocate more than that it has allocated for one class? And does it free this memory automatically when the user has got offline or change to different php page? How it is recognizing same variables which created for different users if its true? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [You're going to want to read the first several links here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+memory+management&rlz=1C1GTPM___US647US648&oq=php+memory+man&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4775j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Term you are looking for is *concurrency* or how to deal with more than 1 person at a time. Short answer is - yes. Each "user" would be using a block of memory allocated to serve their request. That's short answer, it doesn't tackle the efficiency, the nature of CGI apps etc. There must be a reason you're asking this, so if there's an underlying problem you're trying to solve - do tell.

Comment: I just wanted to make a class Users then store several user information inside of it. I taught it would be more readable for me (writing-reading database, publishing in page from just one name of variable) but dont know about how it will treat. thank for answer tho:)